# ReactiveMongo aggregate count function

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I'm trying to perform a ReactiveMongo aggregate call 
**Input:** x of type X, y of type Y, list of types Z ( z : Z*) 
**Output:**
need to count all the records at mongodb such that:
X field = x,
Y field = y,
and Z field in the list of types Z, how can i aggregate that? 
**Code Example:**

```
collection.count(Some(Json.obj(
      X -> x,
      Y -> y,
      Z -> (Need to contain one of the Z Elements)
    ))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using $in aggregation

```
collection.count(Some(Json.obj(
  X -> x,
  Y -> y,
  Z -> Json.obj("$in" -> YOUR_LIST)
))
```